# Django multiple radio input from HTML form with same name

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I am having a problem with `Django` forms. I am currently using the request.POST to validate the POST within views.

I want to send inputed-data(`radio` type) from my template with the same name.

In my `template.py`:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'app:AnsSubmission' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}

  {% for i in Exam %}
  <div class="form-group col-xl-12">
    <label>{{ i.question }}</label>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" class="mx-2" name="givenAns" array_column="{{ i.pk }} value="True" required>True</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" class="mx-2" name="givenAns" array_column="{{ i.pk }} value="False" required>False</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And willing to fetch these data in `views.py` like:

```
givenAns_list = request.POST.getlist('givenAns')

for i in givenAns_list:
  this_givenAns = givenAns_list[i]
```

But the problem here is this `radio` type input field doesn't take value for the same name(not as a list I wish). If I select answer of 2nd question, the 1st one's selection is unselected.

Please suggest how can I fix this?

Comment: You should have different names for each answer radio set otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Well, In that case, my problem is I don't know how many questions and answers(`radio`) buttons will be there.... what should I do for the unknown number of naming this field? And If I give name with {{ i.pk }} how can I fetch the answer/input from my `views.py` with ensuring the sequence?

Comment: You could append the question id (```i.pk```) to ```name``` -  like this ```name="givenAns_{{i.pk}}"```. Any problem with this approach ?

Comment: @Ram Thanks. This approach can be a fantastic solution. Let me try....